# Restoring saved shortcuts in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, shortcuts

I have modified 20+ shortcut keyins using the QGIS 2.18 Settings > Configure Shortcuts dialog. I save them to an XML file using the Save... button, and the XML file that is generated looks fine (that is, all the modified keyins are displayed).

However, when I load and configure another PC with QGIS 2.18.4, the shortcuts XML I have generated doesn't load on this PC. I click on the Load... button and specify the modified shortcuts XML file, but no changes at all appear in the shortcuts list.

For that matter, I can remove shortcuts for several functions on the originating 2.18 PC, but attempting to reload the saved shortcuts XML file has no effect on this system either. Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that there wasn't a rush of answers :-), I developed a workaround for my problem. The QGIS shortcuts are stored in the Windows registry, in folder HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\QGIS\QGIS2\shortcuts. Right-click on the 'shortcuts' folder and choose Export. Upon exiting REGEDIT, double-click on the exported .reg file and your custom QGIS shortcuts will be loaded. All of this logic depends on being in the login environment for the QGIS user, of course.